# Simplify Slider

Tags: qgis, simplify

QGIS 3.4 appeared to have a slider for adjusting the simplification tolerance - at least that is what shows up in the 3.4 documentation, for example:

https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/training_manual/create_vector_data/topo_editing.html

[image]

Has this been dropped in 3.6 and will it return?

Answer (score 1):

In **QGIS 3.6**, the slidebar is removed and the double spinbox remains:

[image: Tolerance]

---

Couldn't find any news on whether or not the slidebar will return.